# How to add subdomain to private Linux server

Tags: apache, subdomain

How do I create a subdomain to my linux server (with apache) which I can access from outside?

Answer (score 0):

A subdomain has to have an own entry in the DNS settings for the domain. Alternatively you can use an asterisk (*) as wildcard when you want to have multiple sub domains or when you want have scripts reacting differently on the subdomains. Then you should be able to set it up in Plesk, CPanel or whatever you use. When you do it in the Apache files, you should be able to set it up as a virtual host like any other domain, too.